# Оператор or работает не так, как нужно

Tags: python, python-3.x, логические-выражения, приоритет

Пытаюсь написать шахматы на Python. Крайне редко использую оператор or, но в этот раз без него никак. Почему оператор or работает не так, как нужно?

```
old_y = int(input("Введите позицию y (1-8) фигуры\n"))
old_y -= 1
old_x = input("Введите позицию x (a-h) фигуры\n")
old_x = abc.index(old_x)
new_y = int(input("Введите позицию y (1-8) фигуры\n"))
new_y -= 1
new_x = input("Введите позицию x (a-h) фигуры\n")
new_x = abc.index(new_x)
if board[old_y][old_x] == "♙" and old_y == 1:
    if new_y == 2 or new_y == 3 and new_x - old_x == 1 or new_x - old_x == -1 or new_x - old_x == 0:
        pass  # Выполняется вот эта часть, хотя разница между переменными new_x и old_x = -7
    else:
        print("Неверно задан ход\n")
        continue
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за немного неточный вопрос: при значении old_x = 7 и new_x = 0 все равно выполняется блок кода с pass

Comment: Не вчитывался, что там за условие, но вообще у and приоритет выше, поэтому сначала выполнится `new_y == 3 and new_x - old_x == 1`, потом все остальное. Расставьте скобки, как нужно чтобы было именно так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: New_y == 2,  эта часть кода верно выполнялась до добавления new_x и old_x в if

Comment: Скобки ставил уже всевозможными способами, не помогло.

Comment: Не нужно всевозможными способами, нужно так, чтобы порядок был тот что вам нужен. Представьте, что and - это умножение, а or - сложение.

Comment: Надо ставить не «всевозможными способами», а группировать условия согласно тому поведению, которые вы желаете получить. Проходили значение скобок на уроках математики в школе?

Comment: Для справки: оператор or работает так, как нужно. Просто у вас неправильное представление о "нужно".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if new_y == 2 or new_y == 3 and new_x - old_x == 1 or new_x - old_x == -1 or new_x - old_x == 0:
```

У оператора `and` приоритет выше, чем у оператора `or`, поэтому ваша запись эквивалентна такой:

```
if new_y == 2 or (new_y == 3 and new_x - old_x == 1) or new_x - old_x == -1 or new_x - old_x == 0:
```

Если вы хотите сгруппировать условия, которые через `or`, то используйте скобки:

```
if (new_y == 2 or new_y == 3) and (new_x - old_x == 1 or new_x - old_x == -1 or new_x - old_x == 0):
```

А вообще всё это можно записать короче с помощью оператора `in`:

```
if new_y in (2,3) and (new_x - old_x) in (1,-1,0):
```

Или так, чтобы объединить проверку на `1` и `-1`:

```
if new_y in (2,3) and abs(new_x - old_x) in (0,1):
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас пойду проверять)

Comment: Все заработало! Огромное спасибо)

Comment: Если через abs, тогда логично сделать: `abs(new_x - old_x) <= 1`